# Semantic UI dropdown value getting retained, when the table row is deleted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, semantic-ui

A table is rendered with rows based on the values inside the array 'results'. There is a dropdown present in each of the row, which is populated via an array 'statuses'.

```
<div id="app">
<table>
 <tr v-for="(row,index) of results">
 <td>{{index}}</td>
 <td>{{row.name}}</td>
 <td>
 <div :id="row.id"
       class="ui selection dropdown status_dropdown">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="text">{{row.status}}</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" v-for="status of statuses"
           :data-index="index">
        {{status.status}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Following is change dropdown function, which basically removes the row if the selected text in dropdown is "Delete":

```
$('.status_dropdown').dropdown({
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {
        let temp_index = $($choice).attr("data-index");
        if(text === "Delete"){
          vm.results.splice(temp_index,1);
        }
  }
  });
```

Here's a codepen with complete code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxzZOB

Now, if the status is changed to "Delete", although the row gets removed, the value of dropdown "Delete" is getting retained on that row.

To reproduce in the codepen sample, change the first row's status (index 0) to "Delete". You'll see that status for "Doe" appears as "Delete".

Also, if any of the dropdown value is changed. And some other row's dropdown value is changed, the previous row for which the status was changed retains the value.

To reproduce in the codepen sample, reload the page. Now, change the status for third row (index 2) to "Active". Now delete the second row (index 1) by selecting "Delete". You'll see last row retaining the value "Active".

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: First, data should be a function https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function. Then, do not use jQuery for event, use vue.

Comment: The data does not need to be a function for data in this case. Using jQuery will mess things up a bit, and I'd recommend you don't use it, however, I see that semantic-ui relies on it. You can, however, use the vue version https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/

Comment: In this case, I didn't had the requirement for multiple instances. So making data as a function wasn't required. Yes, I know one should avoid using JQuery with Vue. I was able to implement the functionality with a simple select and vue events. However my whole project base is written with semantic ui. And semantic-ui relies heavily of JQuery. Yes I tried semantic ui vue initially, and there were multiple things which were not stable. So I then started the project with semantic ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can define the key. see below:

```
<div id="app">
<table>
  <tr v-for="(row,index) of results">
    <td>{{index}}</td>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <div :id="row.id"
           :key="row.id"
           class="ui selection dropdown status_dropdown">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="text">{{row.status}}</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item" v-for="status of statuses"
               :data-index="index">
            {{status.status}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Defining the key should maintain the dom item instance while it moves within the table.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue :)